# Metabase integration with geojson and attributes

Tags: geojson, metabase

I am trying to implement a geojson and it is deployed correctly but it does not recognize the attributes

```
"fill": "# 580858","fill-opacity": 0.5
```

Is there a way to make a map where states are painted in different colors?